# Community User don't have access to approval request in Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app, community

This is kind of a weird error I am facing. 
When I am logged in as system admin and sending the record for approval from community user the approval process is working fine. But if some other user(not system admin) sends an approval request on the same record I am getting the error in the attached pic.

Any help is appreciated.

[image: Error message in Salesforce1]

Comment: Can you tell us what kind of community you have, the object involved, the OWD on the object and how you currently have record permissions/sharing set up on it? Also, what is your approval process and the criteria for entry?